# Groovy string match 90% (ignore letter casing)

Tags: grails, groovy

I need to write a Groovy function to check if two given strings match at least 90%. I just wanted to know if anyone knew of an already existent such utility method that I could use in a Grails project. I haven't really written the method yet but ideally this is how it would work:

```
def doStringsMatch(String str1, String str2) {
    if (str1 and str2 match at least 90% or
        str1 appears in str2 somewhere or
        str2 appears in str1 somewhere)
        return true
    else
        return false
}
```

Thanks

Comment: This question is borderline "suggest a favorite tool, software library, or off-site resource" which means it could be closed. Please provide some code showing what you have tried.

Comment: @Josh Mein Question edited to illustrate thought process better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a groovy implementation of [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), basically it returns a percentage of how similar the two strings appear to be.  `0` means they are completely different and `1` means they are the exact same.  This implementation is case insensitive.

```
  private double similarity(String s1, String s2) {
    if (s1.length() < s2.length()) { // s1 should always be bigger
        String swap = s1; s1 = s2; s2 = swap;
    }
    int bigLen = s1.length();
    if (bigLen == 0) { return 1.0; /* both strings are zero length */ }
    return (bigLen - computeEditDistance(s1, s2)) / (double) bigLen;
  }

  private int computeEditDistance(String s1, String s2) {
    s1 = s1.toLowerCase();
    s2 = s2.toLowerCase();

    int[] costs = new int[s2.length() + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i <= s1.length(); i++) {
        int lastValue = i;
        for (int j = 0; j <= s2.length(); j++) {
            if (i == 0)
                costs[j] = j;
            else {
                if (j > 0) {
                    int newValue = costs[j - 1];
                    if (s1.charAt(i - 1) != s2.charAt(j - 1))
                        newValue = Math.min(Math.min(newValue, lastValue),
                                costs[j]) + 1;
                    costs[j - 1] = lastValue;
                    lastValue = newValue;
                }
            }
        }
        if (i > 0)
            costs[s2.length()] = lastValue;
    }
    return costs[s2.length()];
  }
```

Comment: [Apache commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) also has a Levenshtein implementation in `StringUtils`. Also worth checking out is the apache commons [double metaphone implementation](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/language/DoubleMetaphone.html), for checking whether two words 'sound' similar when spoken aloud.

Comment: @rcgeorge23 Your comment should be an answer as well.